# Failover Forward IP Packets with port from one server to another

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, failover, failovercluster

Basically none of the solutions online have worked so far.

Here's my setup:
To simplify things, we're gonna assume it's a VNC server,

My setup is a fully integrated OwnCloud and Ulteo. I've already created all the syncs between `server 1` and `server 2`. I just wanna setup fail-over.

So I have one router where 3 computers are connected to it via eth0

Gateway:192.168.1.1

Server 1 is running VNC with IP: 192.168.1.2:5910
Server 2 is running VNC with IP: 192.168.1.3:5920
Server 3 IP: 192.168.1.4 (Will monitor server 1 and if it fails, it FORWARDS all the traffic originally sent to server 1 over to server 2)

Server 1, 2 and 3 are all running CentOS 6.6 minimal

I followed a bunch of articles, but none of them worked

All three servers are connected to the same router, so same network level. If possible I wanna be able to do this using iptables.

Server 3 is where the incoming traffic should go
I have already tried the following routing

```
iptables -i eth0 -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5910 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:5920

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.3 --dport 5920 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.4
```

I also tried some silly forwarding rules, that I cannot transcribe

I'll be more than happy to provide any further info if needed. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try moving the IP address from the failed computer to the failover machine. Linux supports multiple IPs per host. Keepalived would work for this.

Comment: I did try keepalived, but it's not doing what I need, and Moving the IP address from the failed to failover requires that I modify the IPs with ports in the router everytime it fails .... I've already created scripts to automate catch fail, but the packets have to be forwarded, if you would please provide a Keepalived configuration (Just not a one for apache though.. it's a bit different), I'd owe you whatever you ask Dmourati ... Thank you !

Comment: Which articles have you followed, what did you try, and how did they fail? How are you detecting if the service goes down? Do you have a 'vnc' listener on server 3? Is it proxying the connection? Are you trying to route from the router to server 1 via server 3, routing inside the same subnet, with routes on the router?